# Graphical editor for OggKate

Tags: video-editor

Does anyone know of a graphical editor that let's one create and edit OggKate metadata for a file. I prefer using Ubuntu.

Most of the examples I've found so far uses the commandline. 
I've come across "[mmg in the package mkvtoolnix-gui](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge-gui.html)", a GUI for mkvmerge.

I plan to capture video recordings through IEEE 1394/Firewire into the DV format, and then export to Ogg Theora. The editor should be able to insert the metadata (geo location, tags, comments). It is specifically metadata, not subtitles.

Link:

[About OggKate](http://wiki.xiph.org/index.php/OggKate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Xiph Wiki](https://wiki.xiph.org/Main_Page), it doesn't look to me as if such an editor exists.  I would use something like the free [Aegisub subtitles editor](http://www.aegisub.org/) to enter the metadata text at the correct timings, but enter them as subtitles.  Then export from Aegisub as an .srt file, then perform some search & replace funtions on the .srt file (which is a human-readable text file) to generate the metadata strings you need [based on this definition](https://wiki.xiph.org/OggKate#Metadata).  Once you have the metadata in the correct format, you should be able to add it to an Ogg file using [KateDJ](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/KateDJ.1.html).